# Can I find value of start and end of a selection respect to the XPath with Rangy?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, rangy

I'm trying to get the range of a selection in the p, but for example if I select the word "Otto-von-Guericke", rangy.toCharacterRange(content) return different values than those that I want.
I add the spans in p when I load the document and i get the values of range by number of chars in the XPath text.

Andreas Nürnberger start: 201 end: 219 by counting chars in the xpath text.

Otto-Von-Gutricke start: 218 end 235 by range.toCharacterRange(content). I suppose that Rangy count the html chars, and html remove some space areas automatically from XPath text.

Now if I store the value of range Otto-Von-Gutricke finded by Rangy, when I try to add the relative span when I load the document again, the start is over the precedent span and the end 2 chars before. I think it is so because the position at loading time is realative to XPath text.

HTML

```
<p class="blue">
    <span id="form1_table3_tr1_td1_table5_tr1_td1_table1_tr1_td2_p2" class="hasAuthor">Joeran Beel</span>
     and 
    <span id="form1_table3_tr1_td1_table5_tr1_td1_table1_tr1_td2_p2" class="hasAuthor">Stefan Langer</span>
    <br> 
    Docear, Magdeburg, Germany
    <br>
    {beel, langer}@docear.org
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="form1_table3_tr1_td1_table5_tr1_td1_table1_tr1_td2_p2" class="hasAuthor">Bela Gipp</span>
    <br>
    University of California Berkeley, USA &amp; National Institute of Informatics, Tokyo, Japan
    <br>
    gipp@nii.ac.jp
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="form1_table3_tr1_td1_table5_tr1_td1_table1_tr1_td2_p2" class="hasAuthor">Andreas Nürnberger</span>
    <br>
    Otto-von-Guericke University, Magdeburg, Germany
    <br>
    andreas.nuernberger@ovgu.de
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="form1_table3_tr1_td1_table5_tr1_td1_table1_tr1_td2_p2" class="hasDOI">doi:10.1045/november14-beel</span>
</p>
```

Javascript

```
var parentNode = selection.anchorNode.parentNode;
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var rangeOffsets = range.toCharacterRange(parentNode);
```

Can I have the values of range with Rangy, respect to the XPath text and not to the html?

Answer (score 0):

For now I fixed the problem by creating this function, it calculates how many characters change.

```
/**
 * getDifferenceOfNumberOfChars return number of chars of difference
 * @param  {[int]} start         start by rangy
 * @param  {[HTML Object]} node  node
 * @param  {[string]} text       text of selection
 * @return {[int]}               number of chars of difference
 */
 function getDifferenceOfNumberOfChars(start, node, text) {
    var difference = 0;
    var stringOfTextNode;
    var endOfSelection = start + text.length; 
    var substringOfText = node.textContent.substring(start, endOfSelection);
    while ((substringOfText.indexOf(text) == -1) && (substringOfText.indexOf(text) != 0)) {
            difference++;
            start++;
            endOfSelection++;
            substringOfText = node.textContent.substring(start, endOfSelection);
    }
    return difference;
}
```